# How can I make my own std.core module declaration?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Since modules are introduced to C++ in C++20, however, the std library itself can't be imported as modules until C++23.

I want to write code like `import std.core;` so I tries to make my own std library, simply exporting some classes and objects from `std::`.

The file stdcore.mpp looks like this:

```
module;
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

export module stdcore;

// This function will never be used.
// it only exports std::string and std::string_view.
export void __105aw1d065adw__(std::string,
    std::string_view);
```

And main.cxx:

```
import stdcore;

int main()
{
    std::string s{"Hello world!"};
    return 0;
}
```

Compile them with these:

```
CXX="clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -Wall"
$CXX --precompile -x c++-module stdcore.mpp
```

Everything looks well, but when I executes this:

```
$CXX main.cxx -c -fmodule-file=stdcore.pcm
```

I got:

```
main.cxx:5:2: error: missing '#include <string>'; 'std' must be declared before it is used
        std::string s{"Hello world!"};
        ^
E:\msys64\mingw64\include\c++\10.2.0\string:117:11: note: declaration here is not visible
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
          ^
1 error generated.
```

What does that mean?

Comment: `// it only exports std::string and std::string_view.`. IIAC, it only exports the function. I think you need something like: `export { #include <string> }` instead.

Comment: In [https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules) it says `main.cc did not #include <string_view> — it doesn't need to, because it never names that type. The type itself becomes known about due to the exported declaration greeter.`

Comment: *"it never names that type"* As I understand, `__105aw1d065adw__("hello", "world")` would be ok. In `std::string s`, you **name** that (un-exported) type.

Comment: `export import <string>;` seems what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
// This function will never be used.
// it only exports std::string and std::string_view.
export void __105aw1d065adw__(std::string, std::string_view);
```

No, you only export that function, `std::string`/`std::string_view` are not exported.

Instead, it should be something like:

```
export module stdcore;

export import <string>;
export import <string_view>;
// ...
```

Comment: It's important to understand that `export import` will export *everything* those headers define, which will include everything *they* `#include`. Which will likely mean a *lot* of extraneous junk gets exported, some from other standard includes.

Comment: Neither clang++ nor g++ supports this, as far as I have tried. They says `*** cannot be imported because it is not known to be a header unit`